# WPF Fingerprint application Doesn't run on some windows OS

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, fingerprint

I wrote a WPF application for VIRDI fingerprint and it's working correctly on my laptop -my OS is windows 10 and i use visual studio 2016- but on some PCs it doesn't execute.
On some PCs it doesn't execute completely and on some others it had not responding error.
It's ridiculous but it's true, if you have any solution please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You should post some details of the errors you are seeing and also what OS those PCs are using. Another option you could try is insert some messageboxes at the beginning of your program and try to work out where exactly it crashes

Comment: We need to see the relevant code and error messages. Possibly a .Net framework version issue, driver problem or missing dependency problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your care.
My program has problem with some Windows XP and Windows 7, on some of these computers it doesn't run and of some others it has not responding error.
Actually this problem is not about all of Computers, my program run correctly on all PC's with windows 10 and 8 and some PCs with windows 7 and XP.
I try to fix this problem by installing .net framework 4.6.2 but it was not helpful.